# Using ionic 4 css variables within a sass function

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I'm trying to using the following sass function but I get an error, can this be done with ionic 4 variables?

```
$primary-color: rgba(2, 52, 68,1);

:root {
  --primary-color: $primary-color;
}


.overlay {
  background: rgba(var(--primary-color),0.2)
}
```

Comment: this will render as `rgba(rgba(2,52,68,1),0.2)` which is invalid

Comment: Have you already tried something like `background : lighten(var(--primary-color), 80%);` ?

Comment: yes @sebaferreras  that doesn't work either